# How to get coordinates from readable address in Delphi

Tags: android, ios, delphi, geocoding, geocode

How can get coordinates from a given address? I am trying to run this on both Android and iOS platform. I have tried to use the OnGeocode property in TGeocoder. But it doesn't really work. The following is my code, is that I did something wrong? I am new to Delphi.

```
 var sAddr := TCivicAddress.Create;
 sAddr.Address := '(My address)';
  try
    if not Assigned(FGeocoder) then begin
      if Assigned(TGeocoder.Current) then
        FGeocoder := TGeocoder.Current.Create;
      if Assigned(FGeocoder) then
        FGeocoder.OnGeocode := OnGeocodeEvent;
    end;

    if Assigned(FGeocoder) then begin
      FGeocoder.Geocode(sAddr);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should establish couple of steps before.
Try this tutorial step by step: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Location_Sensors_(iOS_and_Android)#Use_Reverse_Geocoding

It worked nicely for me on Rad Studio 11.1

Network and GPS should be enabled in order to work.

Good luck!